# web browser content changing event windows phone

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, iframe, browser, refresh

I am using a web browser in my windows phone app to display an advertisement. I used iframe to load the advertisement link in web browser. After every 10 sec a new advertisement will load.

How can I get the event when the content in web browser changing ?.. ie when the time the new advertisement is loading.

Because I need to parse an xml each time when the content in the web browser changes.

Thanks

Arun

Comment: if you already know its 10 seconds why not use a timer? I know to poll is not good but this should work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a bit of JavaScript that will send a notification to your C# code. When you IFrame loads the next advert, send a notification:

```
window.external.notify("Advert changed");
```

Then handle the ScriptNotify event on the brwsoer control:

```
void Browser_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Value == ""Advert changed")
    {
        // do something!
    }
}
```

See a [worked example on MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.scriptnotify%28VS.95%29.aspx).